# Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses:getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid but no data

Tags: php, dns, smtp, phpmailer

Error message received:

```
Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
```

My code:

```
require_once("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
require_once("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require_once("PHPMailer/class.smtp.php");
header('HTTP/1.1 420 Enhance Your Calm');
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$to = "x@gmail.com"
$uname="rex";
$body="Some valid Text /r/n some valid text";
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;    
$mail->isSMTP();  
$mail->Host =  'smtp.google.com'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = 'me@gmail.com'; 
$mail->Password = '*******'; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->setFrom('me@gmail.com', 'username');
$mail->addAddress($to, $uname); 
$mail->isHTML(true); 
$mail->Subject = 'Forgot Password';
$mail->Body    = $body;
if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message could not be sent.';
  echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the DNS config on your server is broken. [This is covered in the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#dns-failures), but you probably need to refer to your ISP.

I'd also recommend [upgrading your PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/); you're using an old version.